# numpy.ndarray objects not garbage collected

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, memory-profiling

While trying to fine-tune some memory leaks in the Python bindings for some C/C++ functions I cam across some strange behavior pertaining to the garbage collection of Numpy arrays.

I have created a couple of simplified cases in order to better explain the behavior. The code was run using the `memory_profiler`, the output from which follows immediately after. It appears that Python's garbage collection is not working as expected when it comes to NumPy arrays:

```
# File deallocate_ndarray.py
@profile
def ndarray_deletion():
    import numpy as np
    from gc import collect
    buf = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 10000
    arr = np.frombuffer(buf)
    del arr
    del buf
    collect()
    y = [i**2 for i in xrange(10000)]
    del y
    collect()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ndarray_deletion()
```

With the following command I invoked the `memory_profiler`:

`python -m memory_profiler deallocate_ndarray.py`

This is what I got:

```
Filename: deallocate_ndarray.py
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
 5   10.379 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
 6                             def ndarray_deletion():
 7   17.746 MiB    7.367 MiB       import numpy as np
 8   17.746 MiB    0.000 MiB       from gc import collect
 9   17.996 MiB    0.250 MiB       buf = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 10000
10   18.004 MiB    0.008 MiB       arr = np.frombuffer(buf)
11   18.004 MiB    0.000 MiB       del arr
12   18.004 MiB    0.000 MiB       del buf
13   18.004 MiB    0.000 MiB       collect()
14   18.359 MiB    0.355 MiB       y = [i**2 for i in xrange(10000)]
15   18.359 MiB    0.000 MiB       del y
16   18.359 MiB    0.000 MiB       collect()
```

I don't understand why even the forced calls to `collect` don't reduce the memory usage of the program by freeing up some memory. Moreover, even if Numpy arrays don't behave normally due to the underlying C constructs, why doesn't the list (which is pure Python) get garbage collected?

I know that `del` does not directly call the underlying `__del__` method, but you will note that all `del` statements in the code actually end up reducing the reference count of the corresponding objects to zero (thereby making them eligible for garbage collection AFAIK). Typically, I would expect to see a negative entry in the increment column when an object undergoes garbage collection. Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

NOTE: This test was run on OS X 10.10.4, Python 2.7.10 (conda), Numpy 1.9.2 (conda), Memory Profiler 0.33 (conda-binstar), psutil 2.2.1 (conda).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to see the memory garbage collected, I had to increase the size of buf several orders of magnitude. Maybe the size is too small for `memory_profiler` to detect the change (it queries the OS, so measurements are not very precise) or maybe its too small for the Python garbage collector to care, I don't know.

For example, replacing 10000 by 100000000 in the factor `buf` yields

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
21   10.289 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
22                             def ndarray_deletion():
23   17.309 MiB    7.020 MiB       import numpy as np
24   17.309 MiB    0.000 MiB       from gc import collect
25 2496.863 MiB 2479.555 MiB       buf = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 100000000
26 2496.867 MiB    0.004 MiB       arr = np.frombuffer(buf)
27 2496.867 MiB    0.000 MiB       del arr
28   17.312 MiB -2479.555 MiB       del buf
29   17.312 MiB    0.000 MiB       collect()
30   17.719 MiB    0.406 MiB       y = [i**2 for i in xrange(10000)]
31   17.719 MiB    0.000 MiB       del y
32   17.719 MiB    0.000 MiB       collect()
```